# How to get a class into a HTML script?

Tags: html, scripting, navbar

I want to make the navbar smaller when I scroll past the header. So far I got the navbar to stick to the top as planned, but I can't figure out how to access '#navbar a' through the second script.

As you can see I managed to just implement 'navbar' (which isn't shown) but as soon as I tried to implement '#navbar a' it got very difficult so that's the question I need help with. How can I make a var of '#navbar a'?

First file/css/style:

```
#navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      width: 25%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 35px;
    }
```

Second script

```
 window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
            navbar.style.align = 'auto';
            navbar.style.padding = '0px';
            navbar.style.width = '100%';
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
          navbar.style.width = '80%';
          navbar.style.padding = '0, 10px';
      }
    }
```

Comment: the first "script" is a css file/declaration, not a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a class or id to a tag and select the class using that id or class

```js
var navLink = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByClassName("class-name"); 
/* This will return an array
You can either use Foreach or access array elements.
*/


navLink[0].textContent = "Text Changed ";
navLink[1].style.color = "red ";
navLink[2].style.color = "Blue ";
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
       <a class="class-name">Change First text</a>
       <a class="class-name">Change Second text</a>
       <a class="class-name">Change Third text</a>
    </div>
```

Also other best option is to start using jQuery
 So you can easily do something like

var navLink =  $('#navbar a')

Comment: So there is no way to just 'import' something like  var navbar = document.getElementById("navba a") or?

Comment: Using pure javascript you will not be able to do that. You have to use javascript libraries like Jquery to use var navLink= $('#navbar a') . 
You can use jquery cdn 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
Please Accept the answer if you learned anything useful